# Container not fitting to screen and flex-direction: row not working properly

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I'm starting out an application in angular and really struggling getting a basic layout setup; I have experience with angular but actual html/css design is completely new to me

Nothing I've tried seems to allow this container to take up the entirety of the screen. I have tried using multiple different settings on the html and container css classes and nothing will actually fit the container to the screen with width; but the height always seems to fit properly.

Aside from this flex-direction: row does not seem to consistently work. For example, I am trying to get the div "side" and the div "main" inside of the header div to fit next to each-other. Instead of this, those div's act like columns; despite the fact I have nowrap on; I have also tried display: inline-block and that also does not work. I have decreased the width of side and main in hopes that they would then fit next to eachother and that also does not work.

Screenshot:
[Full View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VYA0.png)

```css
html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 15vh;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.body {
  border;
  1px solid green;
  height: 80vh;
}

.side {
  width: 15vw;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.main {
  width: 50vw;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="side">
      <p>HI</p>
      <div class="main">
        <p>HI2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      <p>I am the body</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to start with, there are at least a couple of typos that'll really mess this up, like `<div class="side>` and `<div class="main>` not having closing quotes, and `<div class"body">` not having an = sign.

Comment: Sorry I am at work and had to type it all out as I can't copy/paste into a browser.

Comment: Also the positioning of the container **will do nothing**. If you've set a height on the `html` (although I would argue this should be on the `body`) then `height:100%` on the container would be more than enough.

Comment: Your right, after setting height to 100% on both it changed nothing, but it still does not fit to screen width. Do you know of something to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly - there are quite a few typos in your code. You haven't closed the `side` class or the `main` class and there is no closing div for the `side` div.

Secondly - After I'd tidied up your code, I noticed that you were making the .container `display: flex;` when in fact you needed to make the .header `display: flex;` as this is the parent of the side and main divs.

This is a great guide for flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

This should work for you:

```css
html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 15vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.side {
  width: 15vw;
  border: 1px solid yellow; 
}

.main {
  width: 50vw;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.body {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="side">
      <p>HI</p>
   </div>
    <div class="main">
      <p>HI2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <p>I am the body</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I thought display: flex would apply to all children, not just first generation children. Do you have any idea why the container would not be fitting fully to the screen?

Comment: No problem. When I was working on the answer I couldn't replicate the issue with the container I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you, I suspect it has something to do with my angular project.

Answer (score 0):

main is inside side. if you want them to be beside each other, you will need to arrange them as siblings within the flexbox.

you also forgot to add display: flex on the header css.

try this

```css
html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 15vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.body {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 80vh;
}

.side {
  width: 15vw;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.main {
  width: 50vw;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="side">
      <p>HI</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <p>HI2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <p>I am the body</p>
  </div>
</div>
```